# Parsing the useful content of web page in C#

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing web pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786689/parsing-web-pages)

I am trying to parse the content of web-page in C#. This is the code that I use:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("URL");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
string html = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
{
    html = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

but the problem is that I get all data that the html contains.

Do you have any suggestion on how to take useful data in a 'clean' way or I have to build my own parser? For example: A post containing a title and a text related to it, blog-like format.

Comment: What is 'useful information'? You will have to parse the response yourself.

Comment: Useful is the actual information that the page contains, no hidden tags or other data.

Comment: [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is pretty good for this sort of stuff. Go and have a read, then play with it, and then come back if you have any specific problems

Comment: You will need to use regex class to to ignore the parts you don't need. Actually you will need to build it your own!

Comment: @Mohsenr1: Regex is NOT for parsing html!

Comment: It can be used if you know how to

Comment: Can you give example of your methods?

Comment: wait please, I'm going to make an example.

Comment: Regex is not the fastest solution in each case and +1 @musefan. There are already parsers available to parse html.

Comment: Allright, If it is true, I'm not going to make it. sorry

Comment: do not reinvent the wheel by yourself ! many frameworks are already available

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are indeed trying to parse blog posts from a web page **do not do it that way**, don't even think of using the HTML Agility Pack.

Instead you should use the [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) and related classes that are already built into the .Net framework (since v3.5). These are tailor made for consuming and ripping apart RSS feeds.

Comment: Yes, but only if the website supports publishing/distributing them in this format (as every modern blogging site does)

Answer (score 4):

simply use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It's so powerfull !

You can find many tutorials on internet suc as http://runtingsproper.blogspot.fr/2009/09/htmlagilitypack-article-series.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Regex`. To parse data between two tags (which I assume you want to do) you could, for example do something like this:

```
string match = Regex.Match(data, string.Format("<a>(?<inbetween>.+?)</a>")).Groups["inbetween"].Value;
```

Using a `Regex`, unlike the agility pack does not require an external dependency which is great for portable, stand-alone applications.

Comment: You probably need to read this response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @llya lvanov I'm aware of the opinion but I don't see why regular expressions cannot be used in this context. I know this code is not robust as it only accounts for one match which isn't realistic but despite that, I still don't see why a regular expression would fail in a proper environment.

Comment: `proper environment` is kind of key term here. Web is **not** the proper environment. Anyway, I don't want to be insulting, there just a huge amount of good and simple tools for html, which are, well, a little bit better then regular expressions.